# What kind of trip WILL YOU BE TAKING vs. What kind of trip DO YOU WANT TO TAKE?

Tags: sentence-meaning

A sentence meaning question of:

> 1) What kind of trip **will you be taking?**

Vs.

> 2) What kind of trip **do you want to take?** (If I were to construct)

If I were to ask a commuter about the trip he is going to take I would construct Sentence 2...

What is the *difference* between the two really?
 - is it *how soon* it will be? Or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some circumstances they are interchangeable, but in others not.

The first one is appropriate only when you know the other person has a definite plan or intention to take a trip - not necessarily soon, but firmly intended.

The second one could be used in that case, but could also be used when the other person is merely thinking about the possibility of taking a trip.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of trip **will you be taking** refers to a planned trip.

What kind of trip **do you want to take**  refers to a desire.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference will be in the expected response. The first construction implies the response will be declarative; the decision is made. The second construction suggests the possibilities are endless. The answer you seek might be literal, whimsical, or philosophical.

You might ask an adult, "Where are you going on vacation?"
An adult could respond, "We are going on a tour of museums."
You might ask a child, "What kind of trip do you want to take [if you could choose]?"
A child might respond, "I want to visit zoos [but nobody asked me]."